# Arduino Serial Monitor shows strange ASCII characters

Tags: usb, serial, ftdi

I connected an ArduiMU v3+ via a FTDI-cable to my Mac (OS X 10.10) (latest VC FTDI driver is installed and loaded).

Inside the Arduino-software the Serial Monitor (monitoring /dev/cu.usbserial-AJ038NZ3) shows 
a lot of weird ASCII characters. 
What could be the reason for this problem?

[image]

Here's part of the code I uploaded to the ArduiMu:

```cpp
void setup() {

// Init Serial for use by Send.cpp and Receive.cpp
Serial.begin(115200);

}

void loop() {
    Receive::doTasks();
}

    void Send::flexSensorData() {
    char packet[64];
    int packetLength = 0;
    IntUnion intUnion;
    FlexSensors::read();    // read sensors before sending
#ifdef BINARY_PACKETS
    packet[packetLength++] = 'F';
    intUnion.intVal= (int)FlexSensors::channel[0];
    packet[packetLength++] = intUnion.msb;
    packet[packetLength++] = intUnion.lsb;
    intUnion.intVal= (int)FlexSensors::channel[1];
    packet[packetLength++] = intUnion.msb;
    packet[packetLength++] = intUnion.lsb;
    intUnion.intVal= (int)FlexSensors::channel[2];
    packet[packetLength++] = intUnion.msb;
    packet[packetLength++] = intUnion.lsb;
    intUnion.intVal= (int)FlexSensors::channel[3];
    packet[packetLength++] = intUnion.msb;
    packet[packetLength++] = intUnion.lsb;
    intUnion.intVal= (int)FlexSensors::channel[4];
    packet[packetLength++] = intUnion.msb;
    packet[packetLength++] = intUnion.lsb;
    intUnion.intVal= (int)FlexSensors::channel[5];
    packet[packetLength++] = intUnion.msb;
    packet[packetLength++] = intUnion.lsb;
    packet[packetLength++] = calcChecksum(packet, packetLength);
#else
    packet[packetLength++] = 'F';
    packet[packetLength++] = ',';
    IntValToChars(packet, &packetLength, (int)FlexSensors::channel[0]);
    packet[packetLength++] = ',';
    IntValToChars(packet, &packetLength, (int)FlexSensors::channel[1]);
    packet[packetLength++] = ',';
    IntValToChars(packet, &packetLength, (int)FlexSensors::channel[2]);
    packet[packetLength++] = ',';
    IntValToChars(packet, &packetLength, (int)FlexSensors::channel[3]);
    packet[packetLength++] = ',';
    IntValToChars(packet, &packetLength, (int)FlexSensors::channel[4]);
    packet[packetLength++] = ',';
    IntValToChars(packet, &packetLength, (int)FlexSensors::channel[5]);
    packet[packetLength++] = ',';
    IntValToChars(packet, &packetLength, calcChecksum(packet, packetLength));
    packet[packetLength++] = '\r';
#endif
    Serial.write((uint8_t*)packet, packetLength);
}
```

Comment: You're sending non-ASCII data.

Comment: Or a wrong Baud rate is set.

Comment: I tried all baud-rates. It is always the same.

Comment: You only need to try one: the one you gave to `Serial.begin()`.

Comment: I added to code I've loaded on the Arduino to the initial question.

Comment: This code is not sending anything through the serial port.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Oops, exchanged it for one of the write-function. They all use `Serial.write((uint8_t*)packet, packetLength);`

Comment: As already said, you are sending binary data so what you receive is (probably) right. Try to send "Hello world" and see if it works.

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete; there is no evidence here that `Send::flexSensorData()` is called. Also, since your code includes conditional compilation, you should indicate the value of `BINARY_PACKETS` so we don't try to guess it from your code...