# Getting weird characters from Arduino

Tags: serial

My arduino is connected to ultrasonic sensor and I am trying to read the value from it. When I tried running "tail -f > /dev/ttyACM0" my arduino is sending some weird characters that I am not able to decode[image]

Comment: Did you `ssty`?

Comment: What is that means? Can you explain?

Comment: In addition to the answers, be sure to "Serial.println(sensorValue, DEC)", to be sure it's printed decimally and not as individual incorrect ASCII characters

Comment: Have you looked at the data coming back in hex or binary? That might make it easier to see if the source is possibly using a different character set page in Unicode. The graphics symbols are not standard ASCII. I saw a mention of the source being Audi so it's possible the character set is a European one.

Comment: This other post looks similiar: (https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/12617/arduino-serial-monitor-shows-strange-ascii-characters?rq=1) and I have to ask if you have any documentation or reference on the sensor. It's just as likely to be sending data in binary, do you have any reason to suspect that it should be ASCII values?

Answer (score 3):

It would seem you failed to configure the port on the Linux side. By
default, it is configured to who-knows-what baud rate, and to a “cooked”
mode where the data is preprocessed by the kernel driver. You want
instead to set it to the correct baud rate and to “raw” mode. The `stty`
(meaning, “set terminal”) command does this:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 raw 9600
```

Replace 9600 with whatever baud rate your Arduino is using.

If you Arduino program attempts to read the serial port, it will see the
echo of the characters it sends. In that case you probably want to
disable this echo also:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 raw -echo 9600
```

Comment: I have done this with the right baudrate but no change in the output

Comment: @SanthoshkumarSundararaj: There may be something wrong with the sending code. Try to replace it with something trivial, like `void setup(){Serial.begin(9600);} void loop(){Serial.println("Hello!");}`.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant change the code. I am working with AUDI autonomous car. So it has four arduino micro connected with 5 ultrasonic sensors. My task is to establish the connection and get the values from arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is incorrect baud rate. You can try with a program dedicated to serial ports, my personal choice is picocom but it can by minicom or any other:

```
$ picocom -b 9600 /dev/ttyACM0
```

The `-b` parameter is used for specifying the baud rate, depending on the sketch it can be something else than 9600, the most common ones are: 9600, 14400, 19200, 28800, 38400, 57600

Another solution is to configure the `/dev/ttyACM0` with correct baud rate using `stty`:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 9600 cs8 -cstopb -parenb
```

This will configure the serial port to 9600 bps, 8 bits, 1 stop bit, no parity, and allow the `tail` command to read it correctly, if the communication parameters match what the arduino is sending

Comment: I have tried both but still it is giving the same strange characters